# Picking a time and date with api 16 as minimum?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an activity where I can select a time and date to save in a database to later use on a calendar to highlight days that are saved in the database. I looked into the DatePicker and TimePicker but unfortunately it tells me that i would need api 24 to use a lot of the functions i would need. Is there another option to select a date and time? Or are there functions i can use from the Calendar that are available for api 16?

Comment: Can you at least tell me why you thumb down the question? Just need to know a good way of selecting a time and date with a minimum api of 16

Comment: "i would need api 24 to use a lot of the functions i would need" -- like what? `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` have been around since API Level 1. `CalendarView` is newer, but still far older than API Level 24. I know that they added a few methods to these classes in API Level 24, but they are all still usable on older versions.

Comment: every function i try to call requires api 24. calendar.get(), calendar.getInstance(). Those kinds of methods.

Comment: There is no `get()` or `getInstance()` on `DatePicker`, `TimePicker`, or `CalendarView`. My guess is that you are referring to `Calendar`, and that you imported the wrong `Calendar` class.

Comment: oh so it was that simple... Thank you sir. I feel a little silly but i live and i learn i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few cases, there are multiple classes with the same name in the Android SDK:

- `java.util.Calendar` vs. `android.icu.util.Calendar`
- `android.app.Fragment` vs. `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- `java.security.cert.Certificate` vs. `javax.security.cert.Certificate`
- And so on

When adding the `import` statement to your project, pay close attention to which one of the duplicates that you import, so you are using the one that you expect.

In your case, you want `java.util.Calendar`, most likely.